# How to find path to unmodified file in git repository?

Tags: git

I've modified a binary file. The path to modified binary file is textures/concrete01.tex. I want to open the unmodified version and compare them visually. Where can I find the unmodified file?

Comment: If you'd like to bring back the unmodified file you could always `git stash` your changes, grab `textures/concrete01.tex`, and `git stash apply` to put the changes back if needed.

Comment: git doesnot store the old file but only the differences. So i guess you can git diff and view the differences.

Comment: @AatishSai: this is incorrect: each Git snapshot stores a complete, independent copy of the file. (Precisely *how*, using delta compression in pack files, is a separate issue: the interface Git presents is "complete, independent snapshot".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to extract any particular file(s) from any particular commit(s), in Git.

The simplest and most straightforward is using `git checkout`, but `git checkout` writes its result to the *index* and/or the *work-tree*.  Since your existing, modified but not yet committed, file is already *in* the work-tree, you would, as [Roland Smith notes in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41650534/1256452), need to *save* that file elsewhere before overwriting it in the work-tree.

There is a very easy way to extract or view any file, including binary files, from a commit *without* using `git checkout`, though.  Simply use `git show` to name both the commit and the path, using shell redirection if desired to make the resulting output go to some arbitrary path:

```
git show HEAD:textures/concrete01.tex > /tmp/original
```

for instance.  You can then use whatever tools you have available to compare the two.  Note that `HEAD` names, as always, the *current commit*.  Should you wish to obtain the version found in commit `badf00d`, or in the commit at the tip of branch `zorg`, you could use `git show badf00d:textures/concrete01.tex` or `git show zorg:textures/concrete01.tex` respectively.

There is one **caveat** that does not apply in your particular case: Using `git show` this way *skips* any filtering (smudge filters and end-of-line conversions) that `git checkout` would apply based on a `.gitattributes` entry for the file.  Given that the file is binary, you almost certainly neither have nor want any such filtering.  If there is no filter, skipping it—i.e., obtaining the raw file contents unmodified—obviously has the same effect as not skipping it, which also obtains the raw file contents unmodified.

(Besides this `git show` technique, you can also use a temporary work-tree, or `git cat-file -p`, for instance, to extract arbitrary files.  But `git show` is the command intended for use by humans rather than automated scripts.)

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about `git show`. I learn something new every day here. :-) Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the modified `textures/concrete01.tex` somewhere out of your repo. Then `git checkout textures/concrete01.tex` to get the unmodified version.

Now you can load both into a viewer and compare.

If you want to keep the changes, copy the modified texture back into the repo and commit.

---

If you often have these differences, you could set up a custom diff filter as explained below.

There is a mechanism for generating diffs for binary files. The `diff` attribute. You could put the following in `.gitattributes`:

```
*.tex binary
*.tex diff=texture
```

Then in `.gitconfig` you could define a filter.

```
[diff "texture"]
    command = texture_differ
```

The `texture_differ` program will be called with seven parameters *including the old and new file*. See `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` in the [git manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git).

It *should* output a textual difference between the file. But I guess it would also be possible to e.g. show both files side-by-side in a viewer.

Comment: He can `stash` before he checks out the file else he'll lose all unstaged changes.

Comment: Trivial typo, the second `gitattributes` entry should read `*.tex` as well. The use of external diff drivers is a good point though (hence, answer upvoted :-) ).